# Does Texniccenter or any other tex editor auto-complete references in Latex?

Tags: latex, editor

I want to use a latex editor that has auto completion feature for existing references in a latex file. Do you know any good ones? I am trying to find this feature in texniccenter, but I guess it doesn't exist or I could't find it yet.

Update:
Ok, I found how to enable auto completion in Texniccenter. I needed first create a project. Then open the file in this project (or copy its text). Now Ctrl-Space inside a \ref{} tag completes the reference automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found it. I needed first create a project. Then open the file in this project (or copy its text). Now `Ctrl-Space` inside a `\ref{}` tag completes the reference automatically.

Comment: This is for TeXniccenter I assume.

Comment: Why do you need to open the file in a particular project?

Answer (score 2):

[Texlipse](http://texlipse.sourceforge.net/) does this, also with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

[Inlage](http://www.inlage.com/autocompletion) includes such a function, too. New commands and new environments will also appear in the auto completion list. If you use extern BibTex files the \cite{} command will open a list with your articles and books from you .bib file.

Answer (score 0):

[Kile](http://kile.sourceforge.net/) has reference completion. If you type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> inside of a `\ref{}`, you get a list of all the references (that existed last time you compiled, of course).

Answer (score 0):

LEd presents a click list of them when in a \ref{}

Answer (score 0):

The RefTeX mode for Emacs will do what you're asking for: the shortcut `C-c )` activates the "insert a `\ref`" mode (of course, you can customize which type of reference: fancyref, hyperref, etc) and pressing TAB will allow you to start typing and autocomplete by tabbing again after typing some characters.

It also figures out (or asks if it can't) what sort of ref you're inserting and shows a list of all the defined `\labels` in your document, selectable with the arrow keys or `C-n` / `C-p`.

Now we just need a Vi user to come along and tell us how to do it there...

Answer (score 0):

Now texmaker does, not need any special key.